# Google Maps API V3 Z-index Not Working

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, z-index

I have a map with about 20 markers on it representing the birthplaces of ancestors. The markers are created from XML. I want the later generations at the front and the earlier generations behind, but Google Maps defaults to the most southerly markers in front. In its simplest form the code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map = null;

    var thisLatLng = {lat: 51, lng: -3.5};

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: thisLatLng,
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("php-to-xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("person");
          var gender = markers[i].getAttribute("gender");
          var z_index = markers[i].getAttribute("z_index");
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var comment = markers[i].getAttribute("comment");
          var colour = markers[i].getAttribute("colour");
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + comment;
          var icon = "images/" + gender + "_" + colour + ".png";
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon,
            optimized: false,
            zIndex: z_index
          });
        }

      });

    }


    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>

  </head>

<body onload="load()">
<div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Values of z-index vary from 100 to 200 in increments of 10, depending on the generation. However I've also tried making them 9100 to 9200, and various other things.

I've seen it suggested that the icons need to have a CSS "position" in order to make z-index work. However I've tried

```
#map img[src^='/myfamilyroots/images'] {position:relative!important;}
```

and many variations on that theme without success.

This driving me mad. As far as I can see I have followed the Google Maps reference guide, yet nothing I do will change the way the markers are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zIndex` is expected to be of type Number, but `getAttribute()` always returns strings.

Convert the string into a Number before you assign the zIndex

```
var z_index = Number(markers[i].getAttribute("z_index"));
```

Comment: Untold hours of frustration solved in thirty seconds. Thank you, Dr. Molle.